# Error in displaying data with Angular from json service into a DataTable

Tags: angular, datatable

I'm trying to display the data from a service which I bring the data from a fake json API and then once clicking on the button it send this data to the component to shows display them in the Datatable, bu the problem is that it doest display them appropriately, it shows the data but there is no pagination and it cannot sort them and it shows all the data in the same page.

I've created the demo on stackblitz in this link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sk4hrx

Comment: Of course it will not show you pagination , it's just a simple table , you should design you'r table to being able to apply pagination and sorting.

Comment: As I replied to @Prathmesh Dali :  "but what if someone wanna use it like angular-datatable in this link l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way then how would it be!? I think it's the same way as I tried"

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Pagination and Sorting related logic by yourself if you want to create a custom grid, you can check [this github link](https://github.com/prathmesh-dali/Grid) for sorting. Anyways if you can use third-party components then [Primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) provide datatable component which provides sorting, pagination, filtering, etc functionalities inbuilt which you can use.

Comment: but what if someone wanna use it like angular-datatable in this link https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way       then how would it be!? I think it's the same way as I tried

Comment: Yes... You have to add `datatable` directive to your table tag... `datatable` is a custom directive provided by angular way which internally takes car of adding search and sort fields by manipulating dom and handling all the events...

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding but as I can see that I already added datatable directive to the table tag!